# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.node(...).getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, canvas, data-visualization

I built a clustered force layout bubble chart with d3 using svg (works great on desktop). What I would like to do is convert my code to canvas as it gets quite laggy on mobile.

This is my first time really experimenting with the canvas api so I'm not sure if how I am going about this is the right way. (It probably isn't). When I run my code, I get the following error message in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.node(...).getContext is not a function
```

Here is my original code (svg) that works just fine.

HTML:

```
<div id="happyBubble"></div>
```

JS:

```
  var svg = d3.select("#happyBubble").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "forceTransitionHappy")
    .attr("viewBox", '0 -50  1250 1250')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + -50 + "," + -150 + ")");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

  ....
```

Here is the canvas code that breaks:

HTML:

```
<div id="happyBubble"></div>
```

JS:

```
  var canvas = d3.select("#happyBubble").append("canvas")
    .attr("class", "forceTransitionHappy")
    .attr("viewBox", '0 -50  1250 1250')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + -50 + "," + -150 + ")");

  var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

  var node = context.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

  ....
```

The TypeError is referring to this line:

```
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: var canvas points to the g child element, not the canvas element because of d3 chaining.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that `<canvas>` don't have `viewBox` or `<g>` elements, when you do this...

```
var canvas = d3.select("#happyBubble").append("canvas")
    .attr("class", "forceTransitionHappy")
    .attr("viewBox", '0 -50  1250 1250')
    .append("g")
```

... your `canvas` selection is actually the `g` element, which obviously has no `getContext` method.